# How to execute automatically command at rapsbian startup

Tags: linux, laravel, raspberry-pi

I want my raspberry to execute 2 commands when he  starts but i don't know how to setup it
the commands are

```
cd /var/www/restaurant && php -S 10.0.0.1:8000 -t public
```

i have tried to edit /etc/rc.local and add my command but it doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried entering "How to execute automatically command at rapsbian startup" into your favourite search engine?

Comment: of course , i get many answers that don't work

Comment: Well, that would be info you should include in  your question. Otherwise people will just give you those same answers again. Describe what you tried and why it didn't work for you.

Comment: ok , i edit the post

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* is not very useful. Please show exactly what you put in your `rc.local` script, and also show any error messages. https://askubuntu.com/a/434276 Thank you.

Comment: i put the same command like in the post cd....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "official" way to run a program at boot time on `systemd`-based Raspbian systems (and, in fact, most modern Linux distributions) is to create a `systemd` unit file. There are specific instructions for Raspbian here:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md

The entry `After=network.target` is particular relevant in this case, because I imagine your program will need network interfaces to be up.

`rc.local` is a hold-over from the SysV init days, and I've heard reports of it not working reliably in Raspbian. Creating a `systemd` unit file provides a simple way to test the service using `systemctl` without actually having to reboot. If it fails on boot, you'll probably need to use `journalctl` to see the error messages.